# How to get onchange to set onclick=window.open(url)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have an app in GAS html service with a selection box for files, and a button next to it for opening them in a new tab. I can't figure out how to get it done. The files on the list get their values in a google-drive-file-id form (assume that fileID1-3 are ok), and i have a server script for getting the whole link. Here's how it's done:

HTML:

```
<select id='fileBox' name='fileBox' onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(gotFileLink).getFileLinkById(this.value)">
<option value=fileID1>File1.pdf</option>
<option value=fileID2>File2.pdf</option>
<option value=fileID2>File3.pdf</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Open File" id="linkButton" />
```

Server code:

```
function getFileLinkById(fileID) { return DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getUrl(); }
```

Client code:

```
function gotFileLink(url) {
document.getElementById('linkButton').onclick = // what goes here?
}
```

I have tried several options using "window.open" but can't figure out how to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having similar issue, a native select with options, like, print, open pdf in a new windows/tab, and the change event is not assuming user interaction trust, in Safari at least, and the new tab is being blocked  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but based on maxspan's solution (which was not exactly what i wanted) I was able to solve this in another way:

```
<select id='fileBox'>
<option value=fileID1>File1.pdf</option>
<option value=fileID2>File2.pdf</option>
<option value=fileID2>File3.pdf</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Open File" id="linkButton" onclick="runner.withSuccessHandler(window.open).getFileLinkById(document.getElementById('fileBox').value)" />
```

If anyone has a different/better answer - I still want to hear it... thanks maxspan for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code which can help you to open you desired link on click of the button.

Here is a working link:
 [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/zbbL452g/)

```
<select id='fileBox' name='fileBox'>
<option value='http://www.google.com'>File1.pdf</option>
<option value='http://www.google.com'>File2.pdf</option>
<option value='http://www.google.com'>File3.pdf</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Open File" id="linkButton" />


var btn = document.getElementById('linkButton');
btn.addEventListener('click',GetInfo,false);

function GetInfo(){
var e = document.getElementById("fileBox");
var selectedUrl = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
window.open(selectedUrl);  
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer i was looking for but you gave me a new way of looking at the problem and i solved it. Thank you!